Error while building rust image for RCAR (h3ulcb) board
ERROR: cargo-1.72.0-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/dibakar/ruu/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/cargo/1.72.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.481275' failed with exit code 101:
error[E0463]: can't find crate for proc_macro
--> /usr/src/debug/cargo/1.72.0-r0/rustc-1.72.0-src/vendor/proc-macro2-1.0.60/src/lib.rs:121:1
|
121 | extern crate proc_macro;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
I have tried using meta-rust layer(dunfell) branch. For normal image it was working perfectly, only faced this issue while using IMAGE_INSTALL_APPEND="cargo". Help me in this.
